# Service Fabric Cluster and Virtual Machine Scale Sets (VMSS) with Node Type Name Length Greater than Nine Characters

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-vm-scale-set

As I understand from the documentation for Azure resource naming rules, I should be able to create a VMSS using Windows OS with up to 15 characters.

[image]

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules#microsoftcompute

Yet, when I deploy my ARM template for a Service Fabric Cluster, the deployment fails because the name is too long, which is 13 characters.
[image]

I am using `"apiVersion": "2019-07-01",` for the `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets` type in the template, which appears to be the most recent version.

I can definitely make the deployment work be shortening the node type name but I'd prefer to take advantage of the additional characters that appears to be possible in the documentation.

Has anyone else been able to use more than nine characters for the node type name? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last 6 characters are reserved for node incremental names (starts from 000000 and incremented by 1 for each node). Nothing you can do about it. Use 9 characters max